# "Parameter is not valid" Image.FromStream

Tags: c#

I have a Web service that returns an Image as a stream.

```
public Stream GetImageStream()
{
    // Omitted code ...

    return httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
}
```

In another page I use this function:

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(GetImageStream());
```

But I get the following error when this line is executed:

"Parameter is not valid"

Also how do I handle when an empty stream comes?

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: Are you sure that it responds with _only_ an image?  I would bet there are headers in there that will not work too well with `Image.FromStream`

Comment: @AustinSalonen No `httpResponse.GetResponseStream` doesn't contain headers. They are in `Headers` property. My guess would be, it is an `html` content not image